# new thread in IOS tweak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hook, jailbreak, tweak

I want to invoke IOS system delegate(jailbreaked) in tweak(dylib) for all app, for example

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

I try to do this in tweak.xm:

```
void* Run(void *arg) {
    CLLocationManager *manager = (CLLocationManager *)arg;
    MY_LOG(@"thread->%@", manager);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (manager.delegate != nil) {
            MY_LOG(@"okay1");
            if ([manager.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(locationManager:didUpdateLocations:)]) {
                //...
            }   
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

%hook CLLocationManager
- (id)init {
    CLLocationManager *manager = %orig;
    MY_LOG(@"CLLocationManager->init: %@", manager);
    pthread_t handle = 0;
    pthread_create(&handle, NULL, Run, (void*)manager);
    return manager;
}
%end
```

My thinking is: hook all CLLocationManager's init function, get its reference, and pass it to a new thread, and in these threads, I can invoke its delegate methods...However, this tweak crash at here:

```
[manager.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(locationManager:didUpdateLocations:)]
```

If remove the line above, the tweak work well, and the log "okay1" printed.
So my question is:
1 Is this idea feasible? If yes, how to improve it so let it no crash and works well?
2 If this idea is bad, how to achieve the goal(**invoke locationManager:didUpdateLocations:**)?